# Working example of connecting a Windows Service to QuickBooks...?

Tags: windows-services, quickbooks

Can anyone provide a working example of a Windows Service that connects to QuickBooks desktop editions?

I can get my console application to connect fine using their sample code in the QuickBooks SDK, but it doesn't seem to do anything as a Windows Service...

Answer (score 1):

The QBSDK does not like Windows services (or IIS for that matter) working with the QBW file.  They have a work around, but it's not pretty, and from my experience, not overly reliable.

It requires a COM component called QBXMLRP2e.exe

the [developer guide](http://dev.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/pdf/DevGuideQBFC.pdf) has some information on it, but googling will provide better results.

I'd supply some code that I wrote when trying to use this, but a) it's abandoned and I don't know exactly where it is, and b) it didn't work right in the first place so I don't want to send you down the wrong track.

Sorry I couldn't have been more help.